# Creating an object type with all function properties omitted

Tags: typescript

If I have an interface like:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  password: string;
  validatePassword(password: string): boolean;
}
```

I want to use a utility type like `OmitFunctions<User>` that would transform the type to look like:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  password: string;
}
```

Is this possible? I came up with this mapped type, which changes validatePassword's type to `never`, but I need validatePassword removed

```
type OmitFunctions<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends Function ? never : T[P];
};
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk

Comment: You need to know the property name for that. I want to omit all function types from an object, without having to know every function's name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close in your approach, but the idea is to filter the keys you need first and then pick the filtered keys from the original type:

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  password: string;
  validatePassword(password: string): boolean;
}

type KeyNotOfType<T, V> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends V ? never: P
}[keyof T]

type NoFunction<T> = Pick<T, KeyNotOfType<T, Function>>

type R = NoFunction<User>
// Same as 
// type R = {
//     name: string;
//     age: number;
//     password: string;
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=5&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChnIhwC2EAXMumFKAOYDc+yct5hArsQEbSMEAOcdOgDuAeygATClRogGTAG5wANsElxIABSGiJkgBSDh4qTOp0AlBS5ixKiHBCMAvrlxgAnvxQBpCJ4AcmJgAPIwACreEAA8EQA0yABqAHzIALw4TAQA2lrIoMgA1gFiMMgRALoAtAD8FBF5lcgQAB6QIJLoyci1hBCK0BRauC45JZ5lFZXuXj7IwQBi7CAIYMBiIHFpmVrACEVxif5BIeFRPkfIy6vrmykps9HIAEoZC2I3axtbGNCPAHoAcgAMokFBCZC4IHIOYoN6ZPAwggEIikcxyBTIlEsNggTg8KCMbECXSmaSUCzyYnAlxAA)